# Postgres copy of file to table failing

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I have the source file, which doesn't have double quotes. (see the single line from file)

> head -1 test
>   123|ABC|US|458764

I want to copy such records into the Postgres table say "test"

test table definition is like

> \d test.txt
>   number integer
>   Name  character varying
>   Country  character varying
>   PIN integer

while copy this data to Postgres Copy failing, as the data didnt have "" for character data column in file.

```
\COPY test FROM tmp/test.txt DELIMITER '|';
```

How to make sure that COPY works, even when data in source file didnt have "" for character type.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the case. look at example:

```
b=# create table t3 (a int, b character varying, c character varying, d int);
CREATE TABLE
b=# copy t3 from '/var/lib/postgresql/test' DELIMITER '|';
COPY 1
b=# \! cat /var/lib/postgresql/test
123|ABC|US|458764
```

As you can see, double quotes are not needed.